# Referencing a method from an SWT class

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have a program which I've built and perfected. I now want to make a UI for it.

I downloaded all of the SWT stuff, and formed the layout of the GUI to my liking. Here's my problem: I need to link my program class to the GUI class. I had this code:

```
conv script = new conv();
// other coding bits for the other GUI stuff
// inside an ActionEvent:
script.mainScript();
```

But it gave me an error message saying

> Cannot refer to the non-final local variable script defined in an enclosing scope

So I changed it to

```
final conv script = new conv();
```

It said

> the method mainScript(String[]) in the type conv is not applicable for the arguments ()

I'm a fairly new programmer so I'm new to all of this. What does it mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: `ActionEvent` is AWT / Swing not SWT

Answer (score 0):

The first error means just what the error message says: since `script.mainScript()` is called from an `ActionEvent`, it is probably inside an anonymous class, which has no access to `script`. Making it final changes it's visible scope. We can not tell you whether you should make it `final` or use some other mechanism, such as passing it as a parameter to your `ActionListener`, since we do not know your code, but you should [read about it to make your own informed decision.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29)

The second error means just what the error message says: your `mainScript(String[])` method needs a `String[]` array parameter, but you are calling it with no parameters, hence the error.

For the record, this has nothing to do with SWT per se. And since you are new, some Java conventions: class names such as your `conv` typically begin with capital letters: `Conv`. Script is misleading name of method/object/class since we are programming here, not scripting.